# How to write below line from MySql using spark.sql? I am trying to Convert string to Date format

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I need to write below code in Spark.Sql using python:

Input Column is in String Format

```
[Month/YearRecordDate]
Feb 2021
```

`SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, fr.[Month/YearRecordDate]) AS Start_Date FROM Table1 fr`

Output Column:

```
Start_Date
2021-02-01
```

So I tried below code but I got error.

```
df1 = spark.sql (f""" 
SELECT 
`Date` = CONVERT(DATE,`fr.Month/YearRecordDate`) FROM Table1 fr
""")

df1.display()
```

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to give `fr.Month/YearRecordDate`?
2. How to use CONVERT function using Spark SQL?
3. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it is working as intended.

```
df1 = spark.sql (f"""
SELECT `Month/YearRecordDate`, to_date(`Month/YearRecordDate`, 'MMM y')
FROM table1
""")

df1.display()
```